# Is Lorna Bucket the Doctor's daughter?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

The Doctor's daughter, Jenny, in series 4 episode 6 dies and regenerates right? Well in series 6 episode 7, Lorna Bucket claims she's met the Doctor in the gamma forests where Jenny (the Doctor's daughter) was made.

As Jenny regenerates, can Lorna Bucket be the regenerated daughter of the Doctor?

Comment: Jenny did not "regenerate", she "resurrected". The terraforming agent brought her back to life. Note that she did not change her form. See: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7995/how-did-jenny-come-back-to-life-without-regenerating

Comment: title is incomplete.

Answer (score 8):

No, Lorna Bucket is not the regeneration of Jenny.

Lorna's first encounter with the Doctor was detailed in *[Lorna's Escape](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lorna%27s_Escape)*, a short story in *The Official Doctor Who Annual 2013*.

The story specifically indicates that her first encounter with the Doctor was when she was a *child*.

It also indicates that she lived with her father (although this could be an adoptive father), and describes the Doctor from Lorna's perspective as "mysterious traveler and his strange wooden box".

Based on the information in that short story, it seems unlikely that Jenny == Lorna.

Also, Jenny was "made" on the planet Messaline.  I can find no indication that the Gamma Forests were associated with Messaline.

Comment: Yes, I've no idea where OP got the idea that the Gamma Forests were on the planet where The Doctor's Daughter took place.